# Find tag that contains certain text and add a class

Tags: jquery, contains

I have the following HTML, and I need to add a class to both `<li>` and `<a>` where the text 'Charts' exists (so not the second line, but rather the 4th and 5th). I cannot change the output of the HTML.

```
<div class="wp-submenu-wrap">
    <div class="wp-submenu-head">Charts</div>
    <ul>
        <li class="wp-first-item">
            <a class="wp-first-item" tabindex="1" href="admin.php?page=charts">Charts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a tabindex="1" href="admin.php?page=add-chart">Add Chart</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried doing this by locating the `<a>` tag that contains the text, but it is not working. Can somebody please point me in the correct direction? Thanks.

Code that I've tried -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(pagenow === 'admin_page_edit-chart') {

        var page = $('.wp-submenu-wrap a:contains["Charts"]');

        page.addClass('current');
        page.parent('li').addClass('current');

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    var page = $('.wp-submenu-wrap a:contains("Charts")');

    page.addClass('current');
    page.parent().addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `:contains('text')`. Other than that your code looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your `:contains()` selector is invalid.

Change:

```
a:contains["Charts"]
```

To:

```
a:contains("Charts")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8KVW/

Comment: Thanks, that was so obvious I couldn't see it for looking!

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do the job:

```
$(".wp-submenu-wrap a:contains('Charts')")
    .parent("li")
    .andSelf()
    .addClass("current");
```